# select, submit elements have 20px right margin

Tags: css, select, input

as mentioned in title , select and submit elements have 20px right margin. other for elements dont ?

```
DL>* {
    margin: 10px 0px;
    background: #aaa;
}

DL>*>* {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 5px solid #666;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 5px;
    width: 250px;
}

<dl>
    <dt><label for="name">Ваше имя</label></dd>
    <dd><input id="name" name="name" type="text"></dd>
    <dt><label for="name">Ваши контактные</label></dd>
    <dd><input id="name" name="name" type="text"></dd>
    <dt><label for="name">Vali</label></dd>
    <dd><select><option>1</option><option>2</option></select></dd>
    <dt><label for="question" name="name">вопрос</label></dt>
    <dd><textarea id="question"></textarea></dd>
    <dd><input type="submit" value="спросить"></dd>
</dl>
```

Comment: Did you have a question?

Comment: i tought that will be self evident that question would be why is it  that those element have 20px right margin ?

Comment: can you upload an example. In which browser? We need full css.

Comment: Use Firebug to look at where that style is coming from.

Comment: please upload the image, not able to understand what is the problem

Comment: Here is vanamondes problem in action: http://jsfiddle.net/9dGkk/ - If you look, the `SELECT` and `SUBMIT` items are smaller than the rest, even though they are set to be `250px` as well. It's interesting - firebug computes width of the `SELECT/SUBMIT` at `230px` where-as the other elements are all `250px`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because form element have slightly different rules regarding how width, padding and border-width affect their final width as displayed on screen. The "correct" way to fix this would be to reset the box-model used by these form elements to the one used by every other element, with the [`box-sizing`](http://www.css3.info/preview/box-sizing/) property:

```
dl > * > * {
    -ms-box-sizing: content-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
    box-sizing: content-box;
}
```

See this live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/9dGkk/1/ and this [Quirksmode post](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/box.html) for more information